# SQL subtraction across two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey everyone I have two tables.. custInfo (holds customer info most importantly gallons on contract) and a addFill table where we add gallons to that customer... what I want is to when I add a fill to a customer that those gallons I added are subtracted from the contractGallons field for that customerName... this is what I have but I get an error that says: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Here is my SQL statement:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

```
UPDATE custInfo SET contractGallons = (contractGallons - (SELECT gallons from addFill where customerName='Strathman, Tim')) WHERE customerName = 'Strathman, Tim'
```

Comment: I suspect you want to return the Sum(Gallons) form your subquery, no? Currently, your subquery will return a row each time the customerName =  'Strathman, Tim'. Run that query by itself and you will see. So, how does SQL server know which row to access for comparison ? This is why you can only return one. Use max, sum, top 1 with order by, or what ever is needed to get the correct result.

Comment: Okay I will try that... basically just want to everytime we add gallons to a customer it subtracts from their contractGallons and updates the contractGallons field..

Comment: Well, the addFill table contains more than one row for this individual so you have to determine which row you want, or what aggregate of rows. Sample data and expected output would help tremendously though. Also is it sql server or mysql?

Comment: Got it working.. now I just have to figure out how to when it gets to "0" not let it show negative numbers... any idea on that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... i can't see your data @StrathmanMedia. But, you probably what to place this at the end of your update column... `where contractGallons > 0`